# Printing to the Xcode (XCTest) UITest Report

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I'm currently writing UITests for an iPhone app and currently use NSLog to print when there is an unexpected situation in helper methods, this causes a false assertion at the test level so it's clear where the error occurs in the test. Then I just read the log to see what the issue was. Is there a way to print this to the test report so I can check all failures once all the tests run? Right now the only log results are the ones that the test generates automatically (such as "Tap 'myButton' Button" or "Find: Elements matching typeButton")

I'm happy to make any necessary clarifications.

Comment: you need an html report for your test?

Comment: That may be sufficient

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can check your

```
TestSummaries.plist file
```

which is generated in

```
/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-name/Logs/Test/TestSummaries.plist
```

If you open the file in xcode, you will see all your test summaries but in little bit bored way. You have to expand all the nodes. But you can make an html report by using

```
xcpretty
```

just use this command in your terminal

```
xcodebuild test -project projectname -scheme schmefilename -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad 2' | xcpretty --report html --output outputfolderdestination/report.html
```

To install xcpretty, use the below command

```
gem install xcpretty
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XCUITestHTMLReport](https://github.com/TitouanVanBelle/XCUITestHTMLReport). It creates an Xcode like HTML report

You use it like this

```
$ xcodebuild test -workspace XCUITestHTMLReport.xcworkspace -scheme XCUITestHTMLReportSampleApp -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=11.0' -resultBundlePath TestResults
$ ./xchtmlreport -r TestResults
Report successfully created at TestResults/index.html
```